# Selecting Text element with SVG.js

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

I'm using the library SVG.js and svg.select.js to manipulate svg objects, I have problems selecting text elements as you can see in this [example](https://jsfiddle.net/a4u9k7qo/). 
With the ellipse there are no problems while this is the error message when trying to select the text: "Uncaught TypeError: this.parent.group is not a function"
This is my code:

```
var draw = SVG('drawing')
var selectedelement;
var g = draw.group();
text = g.text('Perepepeeeee');
var myEllipse = g.ellipse(50, 50);
myEllipse.move(200, 0);

g.on("click", function (event) {
   if (selectedelement!=null)
      selectedelement.selectize(false, { deepSelect: true });
   selectedelement=SVG.get(event.target.id).selectize({ deepSelect: true })
});
```

Where am I wrong?

Comment: You use `event.target.id`. Does your group has an id? Because you never set one. Beside that you would select the group and not the text inside.

Comment: Ok the problem was that the element corresponding to the event.target.id was the tspan inside the text so parent().group() in svg.select.js gave the error.  [In  this way it seems to work:
  selectedelement=SVG.get(event.target.id).parent().selectize()].  Thanks for your help :)

Comment: There is actually no need to `SVG.get` the element in the handler. Because the `this` context in the handler is bound to the group. No need to get fancy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You access the `event.target.id` in your event handler. The target property always points to the node the event was invoked on. In your case thats the `tspan`. However, what you want is the text.

`svg.js` calls the handler in the context of the element it was bound on.
So you can simply use `this` to get the group and search the text-element from there:

```
g.on("click", function (event) {
   if (selectedelement!=null)
      selectedelement.selectize(false, { deepSelect: true });
   selectedelement = this.select('text').first().selectize({ deepSelect: true })
});
```

However, the best way would be to bind the click event to the text at the first place so you dont need to traverse through the dom

```
text.on("click", function (event) {
   if (selectedelement!=null)
      selectedelement.selectize(false, { deepSelect: true });
   selectedelement = this.selectize({ deepSelect: true })
});
```

Comment: Yes true! I had adopted this solution because within the group I could have other elements that I still want to select (eg the ellipse)... but I think you're right that it's not particularly elegant :/

Comment: When you find this answer appropriate you might want to select it as answer so people can see, that this question was answered